# Java - Spring 404 - not found

Tags: java, html, mvc, spring, spring-boot

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Java com o Spring Boot, porém, o Controller não está conseguindo achar o HTML, aparentemente…

Página que não está sendo encontrada

```
Previsão do tempo
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>            
            <th scope="col">Dia</th>
            <th scope="col">Temp. Mínima</th>
            <th scope="col">Temp. Máxima</th>
            <th scope="col">Humidade</th>
            <th scope="col">Descrição</th>
            <th scope="col">Data</th>
            <th scope="col">latitude</th>
            <th scope="col">Longitude</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="previsao : ${prev}">
            <td th:text="${previsao.dia}"></td>
            <td th:text="${previsao.minima}"></td>
            <td th:text="${previsao.maxima}"></td>
            <td th:text="${previsao.humidade}"></td>
            <td th:text="${previsao.descri}"></td>
            <td th:text="${previsao.data}"></td>
            <td th:text="${previsao.latitude}"></td>
            <td th:text="${previsao.longitude}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller de login que direciona a página

```
package br.usjt.previsao.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import br.usjt.previsao.model.Usuario;
import br.usjt.previsao.service.UsuarioService;

@Controller
public class LoginController {
@Autowired
private UsuarioService loginService;

@GetMapping(value = { "/login", "/" })
public ModelAndView login() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");
    mv.addObject(new Usuario());
    return mv;
}

@PostMapping("/fazerLogin")
public String fazerLogin(HttpServletRequest request, Usuario usuario) {
    if (loginService.logar(usuario)) {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("usuarioLogado", usuario);
        return "redirect:index";
    } else {
        return "login";
    }
}
}
```

Controller da aplicação principal

```
package br.usjt.previsao.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import br.usjt.previsao.model.PrevTempo;
import br.usjt.previsao.service.PrevService;

public class PrevController {
@Autowired
private PrevService prevservice;

@GetMapping ("/previsao")
public ModelAndView listarPrev() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    mv.addObject(new PrevTempo());
    List<PrevTempo> prev = prevservice.listardias();
    mv.addObject("previsao", prev);
    mv.addObject(new PrevTempo());
    return mv;
}
 // MÉTODO PARA RETORNAR A PÁGINA INICIAL UTILIZANDO POST
@PostMapping
public String salvar(PrevTempo previsao) {
    prevservice.salvar(previsao);
    return "redirect:/index";
}
}
```

Comment: onde que está o arquivo da pagina fisicamente? o spring tem como padrão uma pasta para arquivos estáticos.

Comment: Dá uma verificada se a página index.html está em `src/main/resources/templates` e se tem o mapeamento para **index** no controller.

Answer (score 0):

faltou tu colocar a anotação @Controller em cima  public class PrevController.